# find X but exclude these?

Tags: find

Original find which works in OS X but not now in Ubuntu 16.04

```
find $HOME -type f -name "*.tex" -exec grep -l "masi" {} + |  vim -R -
```

(simplified version still; you can omit `vim` part but it just shows here that I am handling the results)

In Ubuntu 16.04, I get those permission denied -messages.
I want to exclude permission denied messages from my find; actually those files seem to be mostly .dotFiles

```
drwx------  2 root root  4096 touko 29 23:59 .gvfs
```

I cannot combine the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25234419/54964) to my find of searching. 
So find all but exclude those files with permission denied (`! -readable -prune`).
Pseudocode

```
find $HOME -type f -name "*.tex" \ 
  -o ! -readable -prune -o \    
  -exec grep -l "masi" {} +
```

but it seems to expand too much by giving a massive list etc messages

```
grep: /home/masi/.conda/envs/my_root/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-27/include/linux/power: Is a directory`
...
```

So different than the thing works in OS X. 
I tried also unsuccessfully `-perm a+r` instead of the parsing structure but I still get those permission denied -messages.

### Reviewing Gilles' answer

My final solution is

```
find $HOME +perm 0666 -type f -name ...
```

because `readable` is not POSIX and does not work in OSX.

---

How can you combine search and exclude in find?

Comment: The easy answer is to simply filter out standard error (`... 2> /dev/null`).

Comment: Yes, it is easy but I want to catch my errors, not throw them away.

Comment: `2> find.err`, then you can review the error log at your leisure.

Comment: _I feel it appropriate to add here that if you need to add some other search criteria, that should be done with `-o`: `find . ! -readable -prune -o -name '*.txt'`_ is [one of the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762348/how-can-i-exclude-all-permission-denied-messages-from-find/25234419#comment48051875_25234419) on the answer you have accepted there... and it has 33 upvotes so really, you can't miss it...

Comment: alternatively:  `find [...] 2> >(grep -v 'permission denied')` will filter out those specific errors from standard error.

Comment: I do not want parsing. I added better starting example. I am handling everything in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the question you asked has to do with boolean algebra and operator precedence. Your `find` command reads:

- If it's a regular file, and it's name matches `*.tex`, then do nothing.
- Otherwise, if it isn't readable, skip it without recursing.
- Otherwise run `grep`.

Put the readability test first. This will cause the tests matching the files you're interested in to be attached to the command you want to run on them.

```
find ~ ! -readable -prune -o \    
       -type f -name "*.tex" -exec grep -l "masi" {} +
```

---

Alternatively, since you seem to be on Linux and OSX, use the recursion facilities of GNU grep.

```
grep -s -r --include='*.tex' -l 'masi' ~
```

---

You shouldn't have unreadable files in your home directory. Having files belonging to root indicates that you ran some programs as root (probably through `sudo`) and they left some automatically-generated state files or temporary files behind.

`~/.gvfs` is the root of the [GVFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GVFS) mounting point hierarchy, and it definitely should belong to you, not to root, otherwise GVFS mounts that you try to do (of removable media, network drives, etc.) won't work. Run `sudo rmdir ~/.gvfs`. If you can't delete it because it's still in use, move it out of the way (`sudo mv ~/.gvfs`~/.gvfs.root`) and get rid of it when what's currently mounted there gets unmounted.

Comment: I cannot understand why you cannot reverse `-! -readable -prune` and `-type -f -name ...` like `-type f -name...and boolean Algebra -o ! -readable -prune`. I do understand Mathematics  but here I am confused. Is `-o` XOR or AND or OR? How do you read it? I really want to use the basic boolean logics. Why does the order matter there?

Comment: @Masi Ok, maybe your confusion isn't with the logic but with the evaluation strategy. `-prune` and `-exec` are both *actions*. They apply when they're evaluated, and the boolean operators (juxtaposition for AND, `-o` for OR) are short-circuiting, meaning that the right-hand side is only evaluated if the left-hand side is true (for AND), resp. false (for OR). Thus `-name '*.tex' -o … -o -exec …` only executes the command on files for which both the `-name '*.tex'` and the middle condition are false.

Comment: @Masi Think of juxtaposition as “if … then …” and of `-o` as “if not … then …”.

Comment: Command `! -readable -prune` says *if not readable do not go*. Continue `-type f ...` says `then do this. I extended the OS X part here http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/240387/15504